# Can SSIS ScriptTask References resolve to a non GAC location?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In SSIS 2008, the ability to reference other class libraries has been added. Is there anyway to resolve the references to a non-GAC location when deployed to a non-developer environment? For instance, if I add a reference to c:\lib\mylib.dll in an SSIS script task then deploy that package to another machine. Can I simply place mylib.dll in the same location to have it resolved? When I try this I am receiving an error that the specified script task is failing to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I'm afraid putting it in GAC is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have been able to get around this is to use reflection. I manually loaded the assembly using Assembly.LoadFile(fileName) then use the Activator class to instantiate the object. This method works best using a VB.NET script task without setting OPTION EXPLICIT ON.